# jQuery Tabs: Multiple Sets, Custom CSS

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs

I've been using jQuery tabs and I love it. However, if I want to customize the CSS, I have to use ThemeRoller and this of course effects the entire suite of UI compoenents.

I'm trying to implement a tab solution that will allow for multiple sets of tabs... jQuery tabs does that perfectly. But styling the tabs is a huge pain in the ass. HUGE!

Are there any other tab solutions out there that allow multiple tab sets on one page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/index.html
That's a decent one that allows for some great customization.  It will give you issues if you try to mix it with jquery ui and use their tabs as well...

Comment: Yup. I just found this almost immediately after I asked. It's perfect. Well coded... I don't need to initiate each set of tabs, it's one script for all tabs. Very nice. And easily customized.